# How to convert an ATS video with no compression to a mp4 video?

Tags: video, convert, conversion, mp4, video-conversion

I am using [ResearchIR](https://www.flir.com/products/researchir/) software in Windows 10 and I wonder if there is a tool or command in Ubuntu 20.04 which can convert the output of a thermal camera capture that is .ats with no compression, dropping of frames, or loss of data to a MP4 file.

The current file is 40GB and I have 32 GB RAM on my current Linux machine.

Comment: I had a look at the manual and it looks like you should have the ability to export data from this application as Movie --> WMV. Perhaps this would be the best way?

Comment: yes the WMV export is not lossless unfortunately!